# How can I create database table using EF Core at run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I am using VS2017 ASP.NET Core with EF Core to build the app that allows me to manage the daily purchase orders which are kept in a table in a database.

On the web there is an input textbox that allows me to enter the table name and when I click the Create button, the new table will be created. I will create a new table every day e.g. "Order25072017", "Order26072017", .. so on.

1) How can I create new table in asp.net Core MVC using EF core programmatically?

Those new tables use the same "Order" model/schema and the code to get the order list is "_context.Order25072017.ToList();". I am planning to create the dropdown with a list of table names. When selected, it will allow me to get the order list from the selected table.

2) What do I need to do in OnModelCreating()? 
3) How can I change the table name in my query e.g. _context.{newtable}.ToList() at the run time?

The DB Context :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Order> Order25072017 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

The Model :

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Product  { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
}
```

The constructor in OrderController:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
public OrderController(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: See This [Repo](https://github.com/Arch/UnitOfWork) that Implemented **ChangeTable**, you can get the idea from it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's the right approach. IMHO, using an additional (indexed) column which contains the date, and keeping a single table, is the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
_context.Database.EnsureCreated()
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade for details.